# strip method remove space in between words

Tags: python-3.x

If strip() removes the chars we want it to and returns the result why doesn't it remove spaces in between the words.
For example here

```
user_name = ' art rah '

stripped_username = user_name.strip(' ')

print(stripped_username)
```

why dosent print(stripped_username) print 'artrah'

Comment: ```strip()``` only looks at the beginning and the end of a string, see [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/strip)

Comment: Check the documentation of strip() https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip

Comment: If you want to remove all occurrences of spaces, use something like: ```while ' ' in user_name: user_name = user_name.replace(' ', '')```

Comment: so is there a method to remove all the chars we want to from the very start to the end?

Comment: thanks every one I got it

Comment: You dont need to use replace in a while loop, it replaces all instances on one pass through. It will only loop once, but for readability sake

Answer (score 0):

You can use [string.replace](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-string-replace-method-replacing-python-strings/) to do this. [strip](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/strip) didn't work because the strip() method returns a copy of the string with both leading and trailing characters removed (based on the string argument passed).

```
import string
user_name = ' art rah '
stripped_username = string.replace(user_name, ' ', '')

print(stripped_username)
```

Or simply doing `username.replace` as mentioned by [kevin Muller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10195798/kevin-m%c3%bcller) in one of comments:

```
user_name = ' art rah '
stripped_username = user_name.replace(" ", "")
print(stripped_username)
```